# How can I add a link to a new item in List2 to an existing item in List1?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have two lists I'm working with.

List1 is a list of clients with a column for client projects, and other related columns.
List2 is a list of projects, with a Lookup Column that let's me pick a client name.

Whenever I add a new item to the project list (List2) I want to add a link to that project item into the client's Project Column in List1.

I created a workflow to start on item creation in List2 with just one step to Update Item in List1.  In the update list item field, I chose List1, selected Client Projects as the field with Current Item: Project Name as the value.  I did find List Item by Client and the value as Current Item:Client.

When I create a project in list2, the workflow says an error has occured.

My intent is to be able to provide the links to all of the projects in List2 in List1 for each client but I'm not sure where I'm messing up here.  If there is a non-workflow way to relate these two tables together, that'd be great too.

Comment: You can use connected web parts to link two lists based on common column

Answer (score 0):

Without adding related projects into client's Project Column in List1, you can insert the related list in the display form in List1 based on the lookup relationship. Once we create a lookup column, from the target list's point of view, the list that contains the lookup field is a related list.

Edit the display form of List1, open Insert tab -> insert related list -> select List2.

[image]

After that, user can view the related projects in the display form when viewing the client in List1.

Information about how to display related list in the target list:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632

Answer (score 0):

When you have lookup column in project list then why are you managing project link in Client list? clients may have multiple projects so managing link would be difficult in your case.

You can use webpart connection to see client wise projects.

[image]